# Same machine, different app domains, same GUIDs coming up

Tags: c#, guid, appdomain

I'm fairly certain I'm either doing something wrong, or understanding something wrong. It's hard to give a piece of code to show my problem, so I'm going to try explaining my scenario, with the outcome.

I'm starting up several instances of a DLL, in the same console application, but in it's own app domain. I then generated a Guid.NewGuid() that I assign to a class in the instance, and set the application's folder to a new folder. This works great so far. I can see everything works great, and my instances are seperated. However... when I started changing my app's folder to the same name as the unique GUID generated for that class I started picking up anomolies.

It works fine, when I instantiate the new instances slowly, but when I hammer new ones in, the application started picking up data in its folder, when it started up. After some investigation, I found that its because that folder already exist, due to that GUID already being instantiated. On further investigation, I can see that the machine takes a bit of a pause, and then continues to generated the new instances, all with the same GUID.

I understand that the GUID generating algorithm uses the MAC as part of it, but I was under the impression that even if the same machine, at the same exact moment generates two GUIDs, it would still be unique.

Am I correct in that statement? Where am I wrong?

Code :

```
Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
string myFolder = Path.Combine(baseFolder, guid.ToString());
AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
Console.WriteLine($"{ad.Id} - {guid.ToString()}");

string newHiveDll = Path.Combine(myFolder, "HiveDriveLibrary.dll");
if (!Directory.Exists(myFolder))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(myFolder);
}
if (!File.Exists(newHiveDll))
{
    File.Copy(hiveDll, newHiveDll);
}
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(myFolder);

var client = ServiceHelper.CreateServiceClient(serviceURL);

ElementConfig config = new ElementConfig();
ElementConfig fromFile = ElementConfigManager.GetElementConfig();
if (fromFile == null)
{
    config.ElementGUID = guid;
    config.LocalServiceURL = serviceURL;
    config.RegisterURL = registerServiceURL;
}
else
{
    config = fromFile;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it is generating the same Guid? And not that you code is just re-using the same Guid? You are going to have to post the shortest amount of code that can replicate the problem

Comment: That's the first thing I thought as well, but due to being in different app domains, surely they wont be able to re-use the GUID? I'll paste a piece of code that I use the generate the GUID.

Comment: `Guid.NewGuid` doesn't use MAC (that was the GUID generation that was the default in ~2000), but it should avoid collisions. I'd second that it's some other form of "contamination" where something you think is isolated is in fact being shared and that's giving the *appearance* that it's a GUID collision.

Comment: A little light reading and quick googling does show this is a potential problem. Seems like time is part of the seed, so if they're created in what amounts to the same moment, with all other details being the same, then there is a chance of duplication. Couldn't find any answers to how to avoid it though.

Comment: @gilliduck Yet, [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms688568.aspx) says: _"To a very high degree of certainty, this function returns a unique value – **no other invocation**, on the same or any other system (networked or not), **should return the same value**."_ (CoCreateGuid is called by NewGuid) - But of course, it's "should" not "does" ...

Comment: @Fildor I completely agree, however just google duplicate GUID and you'll find a handful of pages with the same story, it's one of those cases of shouldn't, but apparently if things line up just so, it can.

Comment: Where do you call that Guid generation code? From the console application? Because you say that you pass the Guid to the "instance" (which I assume means the DLL instance)

Comment: @gilliduck Yes. And "to a very high degree of certainty" doesn't improve things much neither.

Comment: Current Directory is a *per process* concept. That's your inadvertent sharing

Comment: @musefan. Correct, I call the = Guid.NewGuid() from the newly instatiated DLL (see code edit above). That piece of code is what my entry point into the DLL.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Bingo. That was it. Thank you very much, resolved my problem. Not GUID related at all...

Comment: `" Not GUID related at all.."`... we never doubted it

Comment: @Fildor - the person writing the documentation was being *technically correct* (which is of course the best form of being correct). There can be collisions, but they're winning the lottery multiple weeks running kind of chances. But they cannot bring themselves to write that collisions aren't possible because that's not, technically, accurate.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I am aware of that. And I am glad it turned out OP did not accidentally find a way to hit that tiny chance with high probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Directory.SetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_Directory_SetCurrentDirectory_System_String_) is a thin wrapper atop the Kernel 32 function [`SetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_Directory_SetCurrentDirectory_System_String_).

Unfortunately, the .NET [documentation writers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.setcurrentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) didn't choose to copy the warning from the [native function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Multithreaded applications and shared library code should not use the **SetCurrentDirectory** function and should avoid using relative path names. The current directory state written by the **SetCurrentDirectory** function is stored as a global variable in each process, therefore multithreaded applications cannot reliably use this value without possible data corruption from other threads that may also be reading or setting this value

It's your reliance on this function that's creating the appearance that multiple threads have magically selected exactly the same GUID value.

Comment: Correct. What you're not seeing, is that I load a config file (from the current directory), that contains the GUID. When it doesn't exist, it creates a new GUID, drops it into the config. Then the other AppDomain (that's now also in the "other" folder) picks up that config, and doesn't set the GUID to an actual new GUID.